# Django conditional unique together

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model that looks like the following:

```
class LibraryEntry(models.Model):
  host_lib_song_id = models.IntegerField()
  song = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  artist = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  album = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  owning_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now, if I so a select where `is_deleted=False`, the combination of `host_lib_song_id` and `owning_user` should be unique. How can I express this?

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together , or would that not work because they're only unique if `is_deleted=False`?

Comment: Yea, I tried that. But my is_deleted=False throws a monkey wrench in that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Overriding [`validate_unique`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique) to check the uniqueness if `is_deleted` is `False` is more appropriate:

```
...

def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
    if not self.is_deleted and \
       LibraryEntry.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).filter(host_lib_song_id=self.host_lib_song_id, owning_user=self.owning_user).exists():
        raise ValidationError('Some error message about uniqueness required')
    super(LibraryEntry, self).validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
```

Comment: What's with the `PageSection` thing? Is that a typo? Also, I think I want `if self.is_deleted` because I only want to enforce this on things that _aren't_ deleted. Right?

Comment: Correct on both accounts. Copied it form a project I'm working on and didn't catch everything. Answer updated.

Comment: Doesn't unique together generate a database constraint? Overriding `validate_unique` will prevent Django from running the uniqueness checks, but then you'd get an integrity error when you try to save to db.

Comment: @Alasdair: you're correct. I forgot it was enforced at the database level. Overriding `validate_unique` is still the appropriate method, but you need to do the validation yourself instead of using the constraint. Code updated above.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot express this through the `Meta.unique_together` constraint, but through [django's model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects):

```
class LibraryEntry(models.Model):
    def clean(self):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        try:
            # try to find a duplicate entry and exclude 'self'
            duplicate = LibraryEntry.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk)\
                .get(owning_user=self.owning_user, 
                     host_lib_song_id=self.host_lib_song_id,
                     is_deleted=False)
            raise ValidationError('Library Entry already exists!')
        except: LibraryEntry.DoesNotExist:
            # no duplicate found
            pass
```

Comment: this is not enforced at the database level

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UniqueConstraint` if you're using Django 2.2 +.
You can see the full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939490/unique-together-constraint-including-specific-field-value/59476673#59476673).