# Unique together constraint including specific field value

Tags: python, django

For one of my models, I need to ensure the [unicity](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) of some rows, but only in a certain case.  Only the "validated" rows should follow this constraint.

Basically, I'm looking forward something like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField()
    field_b = models.CharField()
    validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('field_a', 'field_b', 'validated=True'),)
```

Comment: using `unique_together` is enforced at db level by issuing `UNIQUE` statement not at the django level; it doesn't look like (mysql at least) supports a conditional unique.  You could implement your desired  behavior at the application level

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use UniqueConstraint in case you're using Django 2.2+
Here is an example

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField()
    field_b = models.CharField()
    validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['field_a', 'field_b'], condition=Q(validated=True), name='unique_field_a_field_b_validated')
        ]
```

here is the [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/)

Answer (score 9):

(at time of writing, in Django < 2.2)

You can't do that with `unique_together` in Django, presumably because not all db backends would be able to support it.

You can do it in the application layer with model validation instead:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

eg

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField()
    field_b = models.CharField()
    validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def clean(self):
        if not self.validated:
            return
        existing = self.__class__.objects.filter(field_a=self.field_a,
                                                 field_b=self.field_b).count()
        if existing > 0:
            raise ValidationError(
                "field_a and field_b must be unique if validated=True"
            )
```

Note that you will probably have to call the model validation manually, i.e.

```
instance.clean()
instance.save()
```

It is not done automatically when saving the model. On the other hand it *is* done automatically when using a ModelForm, i.e.

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer you can overwrite the `save()` method. It would be something like this:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    try:
        self.objects.get(field_a=self.field_a, field_b=self.field_b, validated=True)

        # The object already exist therefore throw an exception
        raise ValidationError(
            "field_a and field_b must be unique if validated=True"
        ) 

    except self.__class__.DoesNotExist:  # Save the model
        super(MyModel, self).save(**kwargs)  # inherit and call the save method
```

Now you don't need to call the `clean()` method.

Comment: recursion? it's a simple method overload

Comment: Looking at this after 2 years I don't even know why I said that