# How can i limit the number of objects we can save by with a condition and without a condition in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

What is meant is, I want to save only one object with is_featured field true, if user tried to save another object with is_featured field true it needs to give a prompt, How can i accomplish that in django any idea?

```
class Event(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time = models.TimeField()
    date = models.DateField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location_url = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField()
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = VersatileImageField('Image', upload_to="web/events")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'web_event'
        verbose_name = ('Event')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Event')
        ordering = ('auto_id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique together constraint including specific field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939490/unique-together-constraint-including-specific-field-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a check that if event is already created with is_featured true then you can return error else you can create instance

````
if Event.objects.filter(is_featured=True).exists():
   return Response({"error":"Featured Event Already Exists"})
else:
   Event.objects.create(**data)
```
````